# Angular2 - EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular2 app, I want to detect the screen height using `window.screen.height` when I run it I receive the below error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'screen' of undefined

which comes from the code below:

```
<body [ngClass]="{'has-translucent-status-bar': window.screen.height === window.innerHeight}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window is not visible in template. Assign it to a property in your component and than use it in template.

Comment: exactly, like adding the following line inside the component:
private _window = window;